# Change latin number to persian number and add commas by jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want change latin number to persian number and add commas, but it don't work true for me. what do i do?

[**Demo:**](http://jsfiddle.net/39rKM/3/)
Please see my demo, output is `&#1,782;&#1,783;&#1,783;&#1,782;&#1,781;&#1,781;&#1,782;&#1,783;&#1,783;&#1,784;&#1,784;&#1,785;&#1,785;&#1,784;&#1,783;&#1,784;&#1,780;&#1,776;&#1,784;&#1,776;` not a right number.

```
function numentofa(n) {
var digits = [],
    r;
do {
    r = n % 10;
    n = (n - r) / 10;
    digits.unshift(['&#', r + 1776, ';'].join(''));
} while (n > 0);
return digits.join('');
}
function addCommas(nStr) {
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
var oooook = addCommas(numentofa(67765567788998776676));
//$('.numbers').append(oooook);
    alert(oooook);​
```

Comment: @mplungjan No, it is not me purpose in life to debug code which is not mine. The post should contain more relevant information, including "what" and "which part" doesn't work. Is it the conversion from Persian? If so, please *remove all the irrelevant stuff about commas*.

Comment: Please see my demo, output is `&#1,782;&#1,783;&#1,783;&#1,782;&#1,781;&#1,781;&#1,782;&#1,783;&#1,783;&#1,784;&#1,784;&#1,785;&#1,785;&#1,784;&#1,783;&#1,784;&#1,780;&#1,776;&#1,784;&#1,776;` not a right number.

Comment: @jenniferJolie `&#XXXX;` means nothing in JavaScript. It is an HTML escape. Use `'\uXXXX'` in a JavaScript literal *but* to build from characters dynamically, use `String.fromCharCode(xxxx)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using HTML character codes, use actual characters:

```
digits.unshift(String.fromCharCode(r+1776));
```

And instead of regexing on digits generalise it to any non-comma character:

```
var rgx = /([^,]+)([^,]{3})/;
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39rKM/4/)

Comment: In the output between numbers is `،` not comma `,`. ?